# Preference windows addons firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, add-on

I have the beginning of this code to create a preference window for an addon:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE korpuslex SYSTEM "chrome://korpuslex/locale/korpuslex.dtd">
<prefwindow type="prefwindow"
    id="korpuslex-prefs"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    style="width: 42em; min-height: 37.5em;"                           
    title="&korpuslex.PrefsTitle;">
<script src="options.js" />
```

...

I got an "error analysis XML" if I call a parameter from the *.dtd file as in "title="&korpuslex.PrefsTitle;">"but everything is OK if no parameters are used.
I tried to match my code with other addons but can't find why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The document type declaration must name the document's root element type, in your case `prefwindow`.

Change it to

```
<!DOCTYPE prefwindow SYSTEM "chrome://korpuslex/locale/korpuslex.dtd">
```

Comment: Hey, 

 (This error is documented in "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/window", "§note")
 
 Actually, it doesn't work too. it sounds weird because it just can't reach the *.dtd file though the structure, names are  OK
 What I checked then is: UTF8 encoding, rewrite options.xul file

Comment: Ok, probleme solved. One parameter definition was wrongly writen. Thx "paa"